# Duvida sobre Excel, como bloquear colunas?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Olá gostaria de saber se existe uma opção no Excel, que de para bloquear certas colunas para que fiquem disponíveis somente colunas que são editadas sempre...

**Exemplo:** Tenho essa coluna selecionada, e quero bloquear ela, para que toda vez que for fazer alguma alteração, não edite ela sem querer ou algo assim.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, da sim. Podem haver variações de acordo com a sua versão do Excel ou procedimentos diferentes. No geral costuma ser assim, mas pode haver de ser algo diferente. Isso é o básico para proteção de planilhas, ai você pode ir alterando as permissões, e ver oque melhor se encaixa na sua necessidade.

1. Selecione as células e bloqueie as mesmas.
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
2. Após bloquear as células, proteja a planilha.
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
3. Insira uma senha (opcional) e selecione oque deseja bloquear na planilha.
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
4. Caso tenha colocado uma senha, basta repetir a senha e clicar em "OK"
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
5. Salve sua senha em algum lugar, pois se precisar modificar alguma célula será necessário desbloquear a planilha.
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
6. Caso tente editar uma célula protegida, vai aparecer esse pop-up.
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Shift+Ctrl
Selecione a coluna e células desejada, clique com o botão direito-> Formatar células-> Vá até a aba Proteção -> e de um checked marque a seleção em Bloqueadas e de um ok.

Depois vá na aba superior do menu do Excel clique em Revisão proteger planilha e de um ok.